# How to insert an empty row in a combobox filled by linq?

Tags: linq

I have a list of Items, given by Linq from the DB.
Now I filled a ComboBox with this list.

How I can get an empty row in it?

My problem is that in the list the values aren't allowed to be null, so I can't easily add a new empty item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try doing this:

```
Dropdown.Items.Insert(0, String.Empty)
```

The other bit of success I've had is to create an empty item and insert it at the beginning of my datasource before I bind to the dropdown.

Comment: Need to set AppendDataBoundItems="True". Check @Rajapandiyan JJ answer

Comment: Only if you're inserting the item before you databind. You can insert items after databind without setting AppendDataBoundItems to True.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. However inserting the data at 0th position in Listitemcollections after data binding will replace the existing data at 0th position.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Concat() to append your real data after the static item. You'll need to make a sequence of the empty item, which you can do with Enumerable.Repeat():

```
list.DataSource = Enumerable.Repeat(new Entity(), 1)
                 .Concat(GetEntitiesFromDB());
```

Or by defining a simple extension method (in set theory a singleton is a set with cardinality 1):

```
public IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T @this)
{
    yield return @this;
}

// ...
list.DataSource = new Entity().AsSingleton().Concat(GetEntitiesFromDB());
```

Or even better, write a Prepend method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] args)
{
    return args.Concat(source);
}


// ...
list.DataSource = GetEntitiesFromDB().Prepend(new Entity());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aspx Page**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">                        
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**C# Page**

`Dropdown.Items.Insert(0, "");`

Always Set `AppendDataBoundItems="True"` because the `AppendDataBoundItems` property allows you to add items to the ListControl object before data binding occurs. After data binding, the items collection contains both the items from the data source and the previously added items.